# JSF facelet app not working in jboss AS 7

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jboss7.x

I am trying to set up environment for Java/JSF app in my windows 7 machine. I am using eclipse juno with Jboss AS 7 downloaded from the eclipse market. Also I am using JDK 1.7.
I created a very simple app containing just a h:outputLabel tag. Everything looks fine until deployed and run, but the tag doesn't render. What I mean to say is that I am getting a blank page.
The jars I included for JSF are : jsf-api-2.1, jsf-impl-2.1.0-b03.jar,jsf-facelets-1.1.14.jar.
And the usual commons and jstl jars.

There are no errors or any exceptions. Am I missing anything here? Please pardon me if its too simple but this is just taking too much time.

EDIT:
My auto-created faces-config xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

   <faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">

</faces-config>
```

My web xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <display-name>test</display-name>
   <welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>NewFile.xhtml</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>
 <servlet>
 <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
 <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
 </web-app>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you post some code, your xhml page? By default JBoss AS 7 uses its own JSF implementation Mojarra 2.1 which can be found jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/modules/javax/faces/api/main. you don't need to put those jars into the war. What file extension you are using? .xhtml/.jsp?

Comment: @TapasBose I have placed my web xml and faces config xml. I am using .xhtml ext

Comment: Change your servlet-mapping url-pattern to *.xhtml in one of those, remove the other servlet-mappings. Re-build the application and make sure to re-deploy it in your JBoss AS 7. Also, when accessing your page, you should have this direction in the URL bar of your navigator: `http://YourPCIp:8080/test/yourpage.xhtml`

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Okay.. How to open my welcome page on load of my app?

Comment: @hemanth just run your application and the welcome page will show

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza If I run the app the url that I get is localhost:8080/test/ and I need to explicitly request "NewFile.xhtml" and only then it is displayed, even though I have mentioned it as a welcome page.

Comment: The problem is, that the namespace
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"

in your .xhtml is not set

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The jars I included for JSF are : jsf-api-2.1, jsf-impl-2.1.0-b03.jar,jsf-facelets-1.1.14.jar. And the usual commons and jstl jars.

There are quite a lot of mistakes right here. First of all, you don't need and even should not include the JSF jars. Those are already part of Java EE, which is implemented by JBoss AS 7.

Secondly, you definitely don't need and absolutely should not use the separate Facelets jar in combination with JSF 2.x. Facelets is already part of JSF 2.x.

You also should not include the JSTL jar. That one too is provided by Java EE/Jboss AS. If with commons jars you mean Apache commons, then those are fine but they are NOT needed for JSF. Include them only if you want to use them directly in your application code.

If you would need any of those jars (you don't, but suppose), it's also best practice to take the latest ones if you're just starting. From the version numbers it kinda looks like you just took a random old version. But again, you don't need any of those jars. They are provided by Java EE/JBoss AS 7.

> My auto-created faces-config xml:

You don't need an empty faces-config.xml. If you're just starting, it might be better to remove everything you don't need. If there's later something you need to configure, you can always add it.

> My web xml:

For JSF you don't really need to map the `FacesServlet` to the extensions you used. Those are already the default. If you leave out the entire web.xml, your Facelets (.xhtml) page can be requested by changing the .xhtml extension to .jsf or .faces. E.g. if your page is 'NewFile.xhtml' you can request it using `localhost:8080/NewFile.jsf` or 'localhost:8080/NewFile.faces` or 'localhost:8080/faces/NewFile.xhtml'.

Unfortunately, the **only** (IMHO) useful mapping is NOT provided as a default by JSF 2.1 and for that one you do need to add a mapping entry in web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>      
</servlet-mapping>
```

Because your welcome page is `NewFile.xhtml`, you need either this *.xhtml mapping, OR you can remove the mapping entirely and change the `welcome-file` content to e.g. `NewFile.jsf`.

**Update:**

If the welcome page still doesn't show, there must be something else in your project that you either don't know about yourself or aren't showing us.

Try to start over with a very simple project and see if it works there:

1. In Eclipse, create a new Dynamic Web Project
2. Use project name: welcome and Target runtime: JBoss 7.1 Runtime
3. Delete WebContent/META-INF and WebContent/WEB-INF/lib
4. Copy the 3 files from http://arjan-tijms.omnifaces.org/2011/08/minimal-3-tier-java-ee-app-without-any.html to your project. Afterwards your workspace should look exactly like the one in the picture.
5. Add a WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml with the following content:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>page.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Double check you have exactly 4 files in your entire 'welcome' project, not more and not less.

Deploy your project to JBoss AS 7.1. To be sure, right click on the runtime server in the Servers view and click on "Clean..." Start your server and request `localhost:8080/welcome` or `localhost:8080/welcome/`.

I just tested this locally using the exact same steps I outlined, and it worked.

Comment: I did the clearing... But the welcome page doesn't show-up on running app unless I explicitly request it, I mean localhost:8080/test/NewFile.xhmtl, where "test" is my app name. On start of the app the URL displayed is localhost:8080/test/. why is that?

Comment: @hemanth It's hard to say. From experience I know people often have been doing 'weird' things, but without access to your computer I can't see what those possible 'weird' things might be. Maybe you have created your web.xml file in the wrong location, maybe there are still jars lingering around that you haven't told us about. I've provided step-by-step instructions how to create a minimal project that should really work (see update answer).

Comment: I created a new project myself by clearing out the old ones, and it worked out fine. I am still not sure y wasn't it working the first time. I thought there might be a problem with the different jars required to be compatible with jboss as 7 and Juno. I cross-verified with ur steps and its kinda same. Thanks a lot for the detailed answer.