# Richfaces-3.3.3.Final, JSF2.0, facelet1.1.14 with weblogic 12c

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, facelets, weblogic12c

I have issue with richfaces3.3.3.Final, jsf2.0, facelet1.1.14 with weblogic 12c.
Application is deploying successfully. While loading the login page getting the following exception.

### Logs:-

```
java.io.IOException: Error parsing [jar:file:/C:/Oracle_Home12.2.1.2/wlserver/modules/glassfish.jsf.jar!/META-INF/mojarra_ext.taglib.xml]: 
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig.create(TagLibraryConfig.java:410)
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig.loadImplicit(TagLibraryConfig.java:431)
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.Compiler.initialize(Compiler.java:87)
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:104)
    at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.createFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:197)
    at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:144)
    at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:95)

java.io.IOException: Error parsing [zip:C:/Oracle_Home12.2.1.2/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/gems_2.0/n3ib5y/lib/jsf-impl-2.0.0.jar!/META-INF/taglib/ui.taglib.xml]: 
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig.create(TagLibraryConfig.java:410)
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig.loadImplicit(TagLibraryConfig.java:431)
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.Compiler.initialize(Compiler.java:87)
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:104)
    at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.createFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:197)
    at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:144)
    at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:95)
    at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.buildView(FaceletViewHandler.java:517)
    at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.renderView(FaceletViewHandler.java:567)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:100)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler.renderView(AjaxViewHandler.java:176)
    at org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowViewHandler.renderView(FlowViewHandler.java:99)

Caused By: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Error Handling [zip:C:/Oracle_Home12.2.1.2/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/gems_2.0/n3ib5y/lib/jsf-impl-2.0.0.jar!/META-INF/taglib/ui.taglib.xml@41,31]
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig$LibraryHandler.error(TagLibraryConfig.java:376)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:137)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:396)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:284)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.rootElementSpecified(XMLDTDValidator.java:1599)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleStartElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:1877)
```

### Note:-

I have already check the *.taglib.xml version it was 2.0, which will compatible with JSF2.0. Please help to solve.

Comment: Why do you include facelets separately when it is already part of jsf 2.0? Please remove that.

Comment: @Kukeltije : If i remove facelets jar, components are not getting loaded.

Comment: Are you sure you use jsf 2.0 then in Weblogic

Comment: @Kukeltije : Yes, i am using JSF2.0 with weblogic 12c

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14044087/jsf-facelet-app-not-working-in-jboss-as-7